# Simplify foreach on Transform

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, foreach, transform

Is it possible to simplify the following code by using Linq?

```
Transform parent;
List<GameObject> children = new List<GameObject>();
foreach (Transform child in parent)
{
    children.Add(child.gameObject);
}
```

I was hoping to simply write parent.ForEach() but transforms don't have such convenience. Does anyone know of a simplification for this?

This is only curiosity and not necessary.

EDIT: parent is not a list of children but a transform.

[image: Attempt at Balázs' answer]

Comment: `children.AddRange(parent)` if "parent" is a list of children. Edit: Didn't know Transform implemented IEnumerable. Cool!

Comment: parent is a Transform, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Transform is a class specific to Unity's MonoBehaviour. It contains information regarding a GameObject's position, rotation and scale and implemenets IEnumerable, which iterates on its child elements.

Comment: Well, if it didn't implement it, you wouldn't be able to `foreach` over it :)

Comment: @Alox, like some people've said, if you really want a one-liner you should probably stick to your approach but put it in a method so it doesn't bloat your code (if that's your concern).

Comment: @Fredrik Alright, I'll leave it as is most likely, I was more curious as to if it was possible and if it was I wanted to know how, thanks for your, and everyone else's, help :)

Comment: It's a great question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `Transform` implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<Transform>` then you first need to convert it to the generic version before you can use Linq:

```
List<GameObject> children = parent
                               .Cast<Transform>()
                               .Select(t => t.gameObject)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: I am somewhat confused as to why casting parent into a transform when it's already a transform allows it to work... but it works and it answers my question as to how to one line it...

Comment: You are not casting the `parent` itself to `Transform`. The `Cast<TTarget>` casts the *elements* in an enumerable into the specified type. Because as @Hans said, Transform implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<Transform>`, when accessing its functionality it is as though you were working with an `IEnumerable<object>`. It **is not** `IEnumerable<object>>`, but the effect is the same -- you lose type information. So the bottom line is you need to invoke `Cast<T>` to satisfy the compiler by telling it that you are dead sure the elements in the collection are in fact `Transform`s.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty awesome, thanks @Balázs for the information, I enjoy learning about these things, and I'm sure it could come in handy in the future :)

Answer (score 4):

Your case is not going to work out as you expect using Linq. One thing you can do is use an extension method as shown bellow.

```
public static class Extension{
    public static IEnumerable<Transform> GetChildren(this Transform tr)
    {
        List<Transform> children = new List<Transform>();
        foreach (Transform child in tr)
        {
            children.Add(child);
        }
        // You can make the return type an array or a list or else.
        return children as IEnumerable<Transform>;
    }
}
```

and you use it as:

```
IEnumerable<Transform> trs = parent.GetChildren();
```

EDIT:
the magic happens on the this keyword in the parameter. The method gets called by the instance but is actually static. The calling instance gets added to the parameter list. Without getting too deep, it makes a static method available on an instance. You do not need any addition on your own code if you do not place in a specific namespace.

Comment: Wouldn't this require modifying Transform? Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Shouldn't I instead be passing parent as a parameter of GetChildren(parent);?

Comment: @Alox This is an "extension method" that only *appears* to modify the transform class (see the `this` keyword before the first param). You *can* use it as in the post.

Comment: @HansKesting ... okay, where then does the extension method go? I tried it as is on my side and it was unable to find the extension method when it was a few lines under...

Comment: @Alox [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). Basically you need to put it in a static class and use a `using` to the namespace of that class in the class where you want to use it.